# Parse.com PFuser.currentuser always logged in with iPhone 6 plus

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

If I run the following on an **iPhone 6 PLUS** simulator currentUser is never nil

```
PFUser.logOut()
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() // this will now be nil
```

If I run on **iPhone** an **iPhone 5** or **iPhone 6** it works as expected .

I'm using **Xcode 6** and **swift**.

Is this a known issue on Parse SDK or am I don thing wrong.  If its a known issues then it implies Parse SDK is unusable and insecure on an iPhone 6 plus

Comment: Have you tried resetting the iPhone 6 plus simulator?

Comment: Yes I tried that - it made no difference

Answer (score 1):

It was my own mistake....

I wrote :

```
PFUser.logOut()
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
if currentUser != nil {}
```

It should be :

```
PFUser.logOut()
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
if currentUser == nil {}
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me too